# make PDF with external sources

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

is there anyone who tried to make PDF file with external sources like images/style/scripts?
These external sources should be loaded from internet whenever is PDF opened.

Somebody told me that metasploit can do it, bud I didn't find out how to.

Comment: You can't do this by design, as far as I know - it would raise a remote notification that the file had been opened, creating a potential privacy risk. However, as you imply, it is conceivable that a vulnerability exists in publicly available reader software.

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file is not a webpage, you shouldn't rely on online resources to be displayed in it when you **open** it.

However, if you mean using online resources when you **create** a PDF file, I would say any PDF creation library can do this. My personal favorite is a Java lib called [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com). If you prefer C#, it's been ported as [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).